# User Deletion API: userDeletionRequests:upsert

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying newly released User Deletion API:

[userDeletionRequests:upsert](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/userdeletion/v3/reference/userDeletion/userDeletionRequest)

Here's API Response, for 2 records (users) I tried delete

with parameters set: {'deletionRequestTime': '2016-02-14T00:00:00.0-08:00'}

```
res: <Response [200]>
res.text: {"kind":"analytics#userDeletionRequest","id": 
{"type":"CLIENT_ID","userId":"8396004.1987248867"},"webPropertyId":"UA- 
XXXX-Y","deletionRequestTime":"2018-05-24T20:57:27.617Z"}


res: <Response [200]>
res.text: {"kind":"analytics#userDeletionRequest","id":   
{"type":"CLIENT_ID","userId":"805053347.1511735850"},"webPropertyId":"UA- 
XXXX-Y","deletionRequestTime":"2018-05-24T20:57:29.764Z"}
```

The API Responses 200 seems ok, but when I checked the User Explorer reports (since 1st Nov) in GA interface, these users still appear... is that normal? (I had expected these rows to disappear for the date range data is deleted) How can we confirm from the GA UI that user data has actually been deleted!

Cheers and thanks for any clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vibhor,

The Google Analytics User Deletion API does not currently provide information about the deletion status, and the actual wipe out can be delayed.

Thanks,
Ilya

The Google Analytics API Team

Comment: Thanks for clarification. So, assuming that 200 OK response can be taken as signal that request has been successfully received by the backend.